# How do I get a prompt every 10 minutes “is this necessary”

Tags: kubuntu, kde, notification

I have internet addiction , and would like a dialog/notification every 10 minutes that says “is this necessary”.

is there a software for this.

> kubuntu 21.04

Comment: Learn to write a bash script. It's exciting. You will need: 1.) a(n infinite) loop (likely a `while` loop), 2.) a timeout (implemented with the `sleep` command), and 3.) a dialog box, which is made straightforward by the `zenity` package. Here is a generic tutorial for bash scripts: https://linuxconfig.org/bash-scripting-tutorial-for-beginners, and two links for a familiarization with zenity: https://www.linux.com/news/create-gui-dialogs-gnome-and-kde/ and https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-display-gui-dialogs-in-bash-script-using-zenity/

Comment: Your life will benefit more from you learning how to restrain yourself without the need of this kind of "solution" ;-)

Comment: @Levente - `Learn to write a bash script. It's exciting`: getting a new addiction may well fix an old one.

Answer (score 8):

It appears to me that you are seeking a technical solution for a non-technical problem. That rarely works. Maybe try getting a human coach to overcome the problem?

Having said that, there are a number of browser extensions to address that kind of problem:

- [Unaddict](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/unaddict/gjpkdldojiaeanjdoifmldjdlgflemkl?hl=en) for Chrome
- [Disengage](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/disengaged/) for Firefox
- [Forest - stay focused](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/forest-stay-focused-be-present/) for Firefox

...and more.

But seriously, if you listened inside of you, and you honestly identified that as a problem, seek professional help sooner better than later. Do it for your own sake.

Comment: To that I would add not to get entrenched in the network of stackexchange sites either. Stackexchange is incredibly addiction-inducing; one ingredient of this site is addiction that keeps people coming back, which keeps the communication alive, which makes getting answers fast. Without addiction as an ingredient, I assume the stackexchange sites would work much worse, if at all.